# Photran says "At least one configuration should be available. Project cannot be created." when creating a fortran project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran, photran

I downloaded Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers, Kepler version, on my Debian x64 system, as well as gfortran 4.7.2 from the repository. When I open Eclipse, I select File -> New -> Project -> Fortran Project, then select Executable -> Empty Project. After entering a project name and selecting the only toolchain available (Intel Fortran Toolchain on Intel 64) and clicking Next, I get to a window with an error message that says

> At least one configuration should be available. Project cannot be created.

and I can't progress from there (the Finish button is greyed out). What am I doing wrong? How can I create a fortran project in Eclipse?

Comment: [The users guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.photran.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftoc.html) says that you should select `Executable (GNU Fortran)`, not `Empty Project`.

Comment: @KyleKanos Awesome that worked. Are you going to post it as an answer or are comments it?

Comment: I can post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the user's guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.photran.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftoc.html), you should select `Executable (GNU Fortran)` and not `Empty Project`.